# Ways to solve google's recaptcha under headless chrome webdriver through selenium? Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I was wondering if there was a way for a user to manually solve google's recaptcha under a headless chrome webdriver mainly through selenium but I am open to any other solution.

Comment: Are you trying to integration test your own app? This may be relevant: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha.-what-should-i-do

Comment: you will probably need to solve it manually from a manually launched browser.  You can then grab the token and insert it... (though not sure about the mechanism there) see the first answer from this post that uses a 3rd party solve captcha service: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59925739/solving-picture-captcha-with-selenium-and-2captcha-java#comment106001290_59925739 If I understand this correctly, the 3rd party solves, and grabs the "solved token" before it is used.... that is passed along and they insert the unused token in the form.

Comment: have you found any solution to this?